# How do I disable WebEx Assistant on startup for Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

How do I disable WebEx Assistant on startup for Mac?   I dont want to remove the application completely, but I dont want it to launch automatically at startup.

Comment: is it in your settings to start up at boot?

Comment: I didnt know where to look... @Tetsujin pointed me to the right area.

Comment: happy ending :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try System Prefs > User & Groups > Your name > Login Items.

Select it in the list & click the - button underneath

If it's not listed there, then check either `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` or `/Library/StartupItems/` to see whether it has an entry in there.
It's safe to remove items from there - though they will continue running until the next reboot.

If you want to be able to restore functionality in future, zip the file in situ then trash the original.

Comment: Thx you so much.  This was exactly what i needed to know.  It worked great.

Answer (score 3):

I tried removing this from the user's Login Items, but it re-appeared each time I started the app.  I could not find it in any of system or user launch or startup `.plist` files.

Then I noticed that the "Preferences" menu, where this sort of thing would normally be configured was grayed out.  So I went looking for Webex plist file itself.

Turns out if you look at `~/Library/Preferences/com.cisco.webexmeetingsapp.plist` you'll find a key called `PTLaunchAtLogin`.

I used a text editor and changed it to "false". If the file is not readily editable directly and Xcode it's installed on your Mac, simply double click the `.plist` file and toggle the key to "false".

Problem solved.

```
<key>PTLaunchAtLogin</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: So I removed it in System Preferences and it loaded at start anyway, then I opened the .plist as described in this answer and <false/> was already there...and it continues to load at startup.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple locations where an application can place configuration to achieve autostart or "automatically restart" if stopped. Some don't autostart but setup a scheduled daily start.

I'm using a (commercial) tool to detect those and disable such behaviour: [Lingon X](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/). It's basically a GUI for `launchd`. I especially like the feature that it alerts me if something is added or modified.

Answer (score 0):

DaveANP has this pegged.  I had already tried the accepted answer of removing from login items, but it kept reappearing there.  Yet another reason to use another platform for meetings.

~/Library/Preferences/com.cisco.webexmeetingsapp.plist was not readily editable directly, but opening in Xcode made it trivial to set this boolean to FALSE.